# How to see Less variables which in separate files?

Tags: variables, import, less, phpstorm

phpStorm

I had one very big .less file that I am break into smaller files.
And I'm using one .less file which including imports of others. All works and compiles good.
But It's really awkward to edit small files, because I do not see the variables of the other files in them.

Is there a way to force IDE to differentiate variables from other?
Only idea that I have it's in each separate file write file import from file with variables?

Comment: *"Only idea that I have it's in each separate file write file import from file with variables?"* As far as I'm aware that's the ONLY way you can do for now (but I could be wrong). This ticket is about SCSS, but the explanation/reasoning behind seems to be the same: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-9288

Comment: The actual ticket that addresses this issue for LESS seems to be this one: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-11241

Comment: Sad, one hope on "Less compiler" author. Than will write "@import 'variables';" in each file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@import` should be used to make aliases